# Multiple YouTubePlayerFragment's in a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, youtube, android-viewpager, android-video-player

I am working on an App which shows a bunch of contents and each content is a View managed by a ViewPager. Some of these contents may include a youtube video. For that, I place an instance of YouTubePlayerFragment inside the page. It works fine and I see videos, but the issue is this:

Let's assume there are three pages in the ViewPager, namely P1, P2, and P3. Each page contains a youtube video, V1, V2, and V3 respectively. If I am on page P2 and swipe left and then back to P2, I see the content of page P2, but the loaded video is V1. If I swipe right to P3 and back to P2, then the content of P2 is correct, except that it shows V3.

I added an extra line in onLoaded(String s) in my listener for testing purpose, and I detected that the Video ID that I give to player.cueVideo() as input differs from 's' which is the Video ID that is loaded to the player and this is basically the problem. But I am not sure why this happens. Below is all the relevant part of the code:

```
protected void addYourTubeFragment() {
                youtubeVideoID = getYoutubeVideoID();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = ((Activity) getContext()).getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                YouTubePlayerFragment youtubeFragment = YouTubePlayerFragment.newInstance();
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.video_entity_layout, youtubeFragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();    
                youtubeFragment.initialize(Util.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
}    

public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer ytPlayer, boolean wasRestored) {
    if ( !wasRestored ) {
        YouTubePlayer player = ytPlayer;
        Log.d(TAG, "Card ID: " + card.getId() + " Youtube Video ID: " + videoLinkToPlay);
        player.cueVideo(youtubeVideoID);

        player.setOnFullscreenListener(new OnFullscreenListener() {
            public void onFullscreen(boolean full) {
                playingFull = full;
            }

        });
        player.setPlayerStateChangeListener(new YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoading() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onLoaded(String s) {
                if (!youtubeVideoID.equals(s)) {
                    DialogBuilder.showSimpleAlert(getContext(), "ERROR", "This is different from the original Video ID");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdStarted() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onVideoStarted() {
                TrackingUtil.logTimed(TrackingUtil.EVENT_WATCHES_CARD_VIDEO);
            }

            @Override
            public void onVideoEnded() {
                FlurryAgent.endTimedEvent(TrackingUtil.EVENT_WATCHES_CARD_VIDEO);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason errorReason) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me figure this out? Is it an Android/YourtubePlayer issue? or is it something I am not doing right?

Comment: please post your Adapter of ViewPager.

Comment: @shahins, Have you got any solution, if yes then please post it. because i am also looking for same functionality

Comment: Not really. I ended up changing my code to use the standalone way of opening a video. I have a feeling there is an issue with instantiating several instances of YouTubeFragment. Instead I did:

Intent intent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent(activity, Util.DEVELOPER_KEY, youtubeVideoID, 0, true, false);
                activity.startActivity(intent);